# How do I implement specific interface methods using closure conversion in jruby?

Tags: jruby

I would like to take different actions when an swt menu is shown or hidden, so I am adding a [MenuListener](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FMenuListener.html) to a [Menu](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fwidgets%2FMenu.html)

If I create the listener using a class and add an instance of that class via add_menu_listener I can separately detect showing events and hiding events.  For example using the following Listener class:

```
  class MyListener
    include MenuListener

    def menu_shown e
      puts "#{e} was a show event"
    end

    def menu_hidden e
      puts "#{e} was a Hide event"
    end
  end
```

and then add the listener to the menu via

```
my_menu.add_menu_listener MyListener.new
```

will print different messages when the menu is shown vs hidden.

---

I can also add a listener using "closure conversion" for example this will produce a message whenever the menu is shown **or** hidden.

```
my_menu.add_menu_listener { |e| puts "#{e} was a menu event" }
```

These two sections of the jruby wiki seem to cover implementing interfaces in jruby.

> https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#implementing-java-interfaces-in-jruby
>   https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#closure-conversion

The second section seems to indicate that this "closure conversion" method should work for any interface, but I can't figure out out to get it to separate out the two different methods.

---

**Does anyone know how to use this "closure conversion" scheme to implement each of the specific interface methods separately?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking more closely at https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/CallingJavaFromJRuby#closure-conversion
I see this statement:

> The block is converted to a Proc object, which is then decorated with
>   a java interface proxy that invokes the block for **any method**
>   called on the interface.

I think this means there is no way to tell what method called the block.

What I decided to (unless someone has a better solution) is this

```
show = "Show"
hide = "Hide"
my_listener = MenuListener.new
my_listener.define_singleton_method(:menu_shown) { |e| puts "#{e} was a #{show} event" }
my_listener.define_singleton_method(:menu_hidden) { |e| puts "#{e} was a #{hide} event" }
my_menu.add_menu_listener my_listener
```

Note:
I chose this over

```
my_listener = MenuListener.new
class << my_listener
   def menu_shown e
       ...
   end
   def menu_hidden e
       ...
   end
end
my_menu.add_menu_listener my_listener
```

since I need to reference some free variables as shown above